# Why wont my ibjects deform in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I got a problem with my javascript. My div wont deform when i click on the button.
I think this should be right, does somebody know how to help me?

heres the code:

```js
var divinfo = {
  "div": [{
      "h": "100",
      "w": "100"
    }, {
      "h": "10",
      "w": "50"
    }, {
      "h": "100",
      "w": "400"
    }
  ]
};

//  alert(divinfo.div[1].h);
function deform() {
  for (var i = 0; divinfo.length > i; i++) {

    document.getElementById("div" + i).style.height = divinfo.div[i].h + "px";
    document.getElementById("div" + i).style.width = divinfo.div[i].w + "px";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="send" onclick="deform();" />

<div id="div0" style="background-color: lightblue">1</div>
<div id="div1" style="background-color: pink">2</div>
<div id="div2" style="background-color: red">3</div>
<div id="div3" style="background-color: aliceblue">4</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated // Mcgajver

Comment: should be `divinfo.div.length`

Comment: Just to add to the answers given, `divinfo` is an _object_ and not an _array_. Objects don't feature the `.length` property, but arrays do. Your `div` object property is an array, on which you _can_ query the `.length` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `divinfo.div.length` in your for loop instead to `divinfo.length`. `divinfo` is a javascript object which doesn't have a length property. `divinfo.div` is the array you want to iterate over.

Bonus tip: Have a look at [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). It's a more modern approach to array iteration.

```js
var divinfo = {
  "div": [{
      "h": "100",
      "w": "100"
    }, {
      "h": "10",
      "w": "50"
    }, {
      "h": "100",
      "w": "400"
    }
  ]
};

//  alert(divinfo.div[1].h);
function deform() {
  for (var i = 0; divinfo.div.length > i; i++) {
    document.getElementById("div" + i).style.height = divinfo.div[i].h + "px";
    document.getElementById("div" + i).style.width = divinfo.div[i].w + "px";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="send" onclick="deform();" />

<div id="div0" style="background-color: lightblue">1</div>
<div id="div1" style="background-color: pink">2</div>
<div id="div2" style="background-color: red">3</div>
<div id="div3" style="background-color: aliceblue">4</div>
```

Comment: Thank u so much Mark! You are a star !

Comment: @mqgajver Glad i could help, if this fully answers your question please mark this answer as the accepted answer (check mark to the left of the question). This way other people can see you don't need further assistance.